# Visual Studio 2015 Build errors - The "Csc" task could not be initialized with its input parameters

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio 2015 Build errors:- 
The "Csc" task could not be initialized with its input parameters.
The "Features" parameter is not supported by the "Csc" task.

Can anyone tell me why I can't build a new empty or otherwise project or build an existing old project without first editing my .csproj file?

In a new project I have found that if I move the 5th line

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
```

up to the 3rd line save, reload and then build all is good.

In old projects I have to add the same line to the same place prior to building.

Once this is done all seam ok from now on!

Answer (score 9):

I have encountered the same issue. In my case, I got a duplicate `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` and `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` in my `.csproj`. Deleting the duplicate (the lower version) was the solution for me. It was also due to copy-paste of nuget packages from packages.config and re-installing it.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I don't know what the hell was that but after installing:

> Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Compilers -Version 2.9.0

Everything start working.

Comment: I don't know what the hell that was either but your solution worked for me too! thanks

Comment: Perhaps this has something to do with it: https://forum.ncrunch.net/yaf_postst2787_xunit-issue.aspx